# Filled hard drive, LVM automatically created?

Tags: partitioning, lvm

Long story short, I have two identical 16.04.3 servers running nothing but Docker containers. Though my own stupidity, I allow new Docker images to be automatically downloaded but don't ever remove the old ones. This means that after a few months of use, I have dozens of copies of the same image taking up way too much space. Eventually (last night) completely filling my drive.

When I checked my less-used `server1`, a `df -h` command returns the following:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            477M     0  477M   0% /dev
tmpfs           100M  9.0M   91M   9% /run
/dev/sda1        19G  3.7G   14G  21% /
tmpfs           497M  1.2M  495M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           497M     0  497M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
```

On `server2` that ran out of space, I saw this:

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         477M     0  477M   0% /dev
tmpfs                        100M   12M   88M  12% /run
/dev/mapper/server2--vg-root  19G   18G     0 100% /
tmpfs                        497M  1.6M  495M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                        497M     0  497M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                    472M  106M  342M  24% /boot
tmpfs                        100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Once I deleted 12G of unused images, everything was functional again.

My questions are as following:

1. What is that "/dev/mapper/server2--vg-root" that got created (seems it has something to do with LVM, whatever that is)?
2. Why did it take all of my disk space from "/dev/sda1"?
3. How do I get everything back to looking like it "should" (as it appears on `server1`)?

Answer (score 3):

LVM is Logical Volume Management. It's an improvement over the traditional partitioning scheme supported by the BIOS of computers. It is essentially a wrapper partition, that holds the LVM data. This can be subdivided into more modules as needed by the Linux kernel. They are typically named, and not referred to by number, unlike traditional partitions.

This has been like this since the installation. It's not something that has changed by itself. It is not something you should worry about either; LVM is perfectly stable, and in many senses a great improvement over the traditional partitioning scheme, as it can hold any number of partitions, address them by name, and you can easily resize and move them on the fly.

If you insist on going back to standard partitions, you'll have to reinstall the system in question. It's not feasible to swap the system partition type on a system.

So to sum it up, it's a LVM partition you're seeing. This is perfectly normal and was done during installation of the system.

Comment: I would have bet a pile of money that when I installed the system I did not setup LVM (since I don't know enough about it to use it). That said, it seems I must have accidentally used LVM on this machine and just never knew it until now. Thanks!

Comment: @justinvoelker: It's virtually impossible for a running operating system to change its own partition from unmanaged to managed or vice versa since that requires the partition to unmounted (plus a bunch of other things) which is impossible for a running Linux kernel and any “forced” unmounting would lead to an immediate kernel panic. It's possible to set up some clever scripts that perform the change "offline" on the next boot but I don't know of any off-the-shelf software that can do this.